# How to convert cv::Mat to cv::Vec3f?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to convert Mat tov Vec3f elegantly. Currently I do it like that:

```
            Mat line;
            Vec3f ln;
            ln[0] = line.at<float>(0, 0);
            ln[1] = line.at<float>(0, 1);
            ln[2] = line.at<float>(0, 2);
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can do `ln =line.at<cv::Vec3f>(0,0)` this will get the 3 channels and you can iterate with the iterators or the normal rows and cols loop

Comment: Any kind of `Mat` or something more specific (a particular data type/depth/size)? Your sample already makes some assumptions, it would be helpful to verbalize those.

Comment: yes, matrix is 3X1 float

Comment: @StepanYakovenko You mean 3 rows by 1 column, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way

```
Mat m = Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_32F);
Vec3f xyz((float*)m.data);
cout<<xyz<< endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your comment, you specify that this is a single channel floating point matrix with size 3x1. I'd be explicit about the data type in the code, so I'd represent it with [`cv::Mat1f`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga9747ac59f97cbb93ddd719c4fb3e2d5d).

Now, since it's a single channel matrix, we can't directly access elements as `Vec3f`, since if the input `Mat` was a submatrix we'd get incorrect results. We can use [`cv::Mat::reshape`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8) to efficiently turn the input into a 3-channel `Mat`, and then use [`cv::Mat::at`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) to access the first element.

---

Sample code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat1f m(3, 1);
    m << 1.0f , 2.0f , 3.0f;

    cv::Vec3f v(m.reshape(3).at<cv::Vec3f>());

    std::cout << "m=" << m << "\n";
    std::cout << "v=" << v << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
m=[1;
 2;
 3]
v=[1, 2, 3]
```

---

To be honest, it might be more efficient to just write a short utility function to do this. Something like

```
cv::Vec3f to_vec3f(cv::Mat1f const& m)
{
    CV_Assert((m.rows == 3) && (m.cols == 1));
    return cv::Vec3f(m.at<float>(0), m.at<float>(1), m.at<float>(2));
}
```